# No measure preserving factors for rational rotations (Y)

Tags: analysis, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Definition: Let $(X,B,\mu)$ and $(Y,C,\nu)$ be probability spaces where $B$ and $C$ are the Borel $\sigma$- Algebras of their respective spaces. Let $g:X \rightarrow X$ and $h: Y \rightarrow Y$ be measure preserving transformations.
$h$ is a measure preserving factor of $g$ if $\exists \text{ measurable } F:X \rightarrow Y$ ($F$ is called factor map) such that for $\mu$-a.e. $x \in X$ holds $F(g(x)) = h(F(x))$ and $\forall A \in C$ $\nu(A) = \mu(F^{-1}(A))$.

Now there is following problem to solve:
Let $\alpha = \frac{p}{q}$ and $\beta = \frac{r}{s}$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ with $(p,q)=1$, $(r,s)=1$, $(q,s) = 1$ and $q \neq s$. Let $h: \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$, $x \mapsto x + \alpha$ and $g:\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$, $x \mapsto x + \beta$ be circle rotations. Show that there is no factor map between $g$ and $h$.

My attempt.
By contradiction I assumed such a factor map $F$ exists.
Then I could show that for $\mu$ - a.e. $x \in X$ holds $F(x+\frac{1}{s}) = F(x+\frac{1}{q}) = F(x)$ and I tried to find a contradiction to measure preserving from here. But I failed.

Could someone give a hint or tell me if I am on the wrong path?

Comment: I'm assuming you don't want $p=q=r=s=1$?

Comment: I think $F(x) = 2\pi sq x$ mod $1$ is measure preserving and satisfies $F(x+\frac{1}{s}) = F(x+\frac{1}{q})$.

Comment: Yes, this case is not aloud. Edited the question. Thanks.

Comment: Also for the second part I agree. What I also could prove is that $F(x+\frac{1}{s}) = F(x)$. And here the counter example does not work anymore. Thank you also for this. Do you have maybe also a hint how I should approach this problem?

Comment: why does the counter example not work anymore?

Comment: Say for $s$ odd and q=1, I think we have $F(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{s}) = s\pi (q+1) = 0 \neq \pi s = \pi s q = F(\frac{1}{2})$.

Comment: $F(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{s}) = 2\pi s(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{s}) = \pi s + 2\pi = \pi s$. I don't know where you got $F(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{s}) = s\pi(q+1)$ from. But just very directly, if $F(x) = 2\pi sq x$, then $F(x+\frac{1}{s}) = 2\pi sqx+2\pi q = 2\pi sqx = F(x)$.

Comment: Okay, I see now. Thank you. This means we will not get a contradiction from this point of view. Have you an idea how to approach the exercise or what conditions on $F$ are also necessary to consider?

Comment: I'm pretty busy now, but I think the systems have completely different eigenvalues (i.e. they have no common eigenvalue), so there won't be a factor from one to another. If you don't know what I mean by eigenvalue, each rotation acts on $L^2(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})$, so you can talk about eigenvalues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By contradiction assume a factor map $F: \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ between $g$ and $h$ exists.

Observe $g^q = Id_{\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}}$. Thus by $q$ times applying $F(g(x)) = h(g(x))$ for $\mu$ - a.e $x \in \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ we get $F(x) = F(g^q(x)) = h^q(F(x))$ for $\mu$ - a.e $x \in \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$.

Using that $F(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ $\mu$-a.e. we get that $x = h^q(x) = x+q \frac{r}{s}$ for $\mu$-a.e $x \in \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$. Contradiction, since $q \frac{r}{s} \notin \mathbb{Z}$!

We conclude there is no factor map between $h$ and $g$.